# How to get Block position from BlockEvent in Minecraft - Spigot

Tags: java, minecraft

Ok, so in the making of a plugin for Minecraft, I found a problem that I can't seem to be able to overcome. So the problem is, that I want to get the position of placed Diamond Block, so I can check around that block for other blocks. I want to make an automated farming plugin. 
 'Till now I've tried to do it with

```
public void OnDiaBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent e){
    Block b = e.getBlock();
    b.getPosition();
}
```

and with

```
public void onPlantGrow(BlockGrowEvent e){
    Block b = e.getBlock();
    b.getPosition();
}
```

But the `b.getPosition();` doesn't exist in spigot/craftbukkit API.
I just want to know if there is any way around this problem and how I could solve this.

TL/DR: How can I get a block position from the BlockPlaceEvent or BlockGrowEvent in an x,y,z format?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

EDIT:
Working piece of code:

```
public void onPlantGrow(BlockGrowEvent e){
    Block b = e.getBlock();
    int x = b.getLocation().getBlockX();
    int y = b.getLocation().getBlockY();
    int z = b.getLocation().getBlockZ();
}
```

Comment: Try `Location blockLocation = b.getLocation()`, which can as well be turned into `RegionCoordinates.fromLocation(blockLocation)`.

Comment: Can you transform your comment into an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: alright... done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you the `Location`of that block:

```
Location blockLocation = b.getLocation();
```

The `Location` class allows you to access the coordinates using `getBlockX()`, `getBlockY()` and `getBlockZ()` and also `getWorld()` and others ([Reference](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Location.html)).

And if you want to work with `RegionCoordinates` you can use this on your `blockLocation`:

```
RegionCoordinates regionCoords = RegionCoordinates.fromLocation(blockLocation);
```